# Can you make an editable label?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Quick question, can you make a textfield, that looks like a `JLabel`, but that can still be edited? You could still change its size and its font, but the background + the border should be gone. As of now, I'm trying to do this with Swing. **What you would still see is the small blinking cursor** that waits until you press something once focused.

Comment: This is a bad idea in terms of user experience--many users won't figure out that it is editable since it looks like a label.

Comment: Forgot to mention, you could still see the blinking cursor in the textfield waiting for something to be typed in, I would focus the textfield automatically, once it appears and maybe add in a reference label, which shows you where to type.

Comment: Even if you focused that textfield and had a blinking "|", it still sounds horrible for user experience..

Comment: Well, it's only an experiment, do you know text based adventures from like 30 years ago? Something that looks like a cmd text input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the fact that, that's only going to confuse the users a lot, you could use a simple

```
textField.setBackground(null);
textField.setBorder(null);
```

Comment: With your solution, there's still a border around the field. Do you know, how to hide it?

Answer (score 4):

You can try using JTextField without border and with same background color as frame

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(300,300);

JTextField textField = new JTextField("some text");
textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
textField.setBackground(frame.getBackground());

frame.getContentPane().add(textField);

frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to make an editable label **as it exists**. You can use a jTextField with no border and same background as the JFrame.

---

Having said that, you **can** add a `KeyListener` to your `JLabel` and update your label's text depending on the key that was pressed. Similarly, you can implement a caret using `|` and a seperate thread to make it blink. But as [Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson) very correctly said, *"Anything is possible, much less is sensible"*.

Cheers.

Comment: Lmao how can I star this comment

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it :D Anything is possible. So the ways i can think (Although i havent tried them) is either by mending the background of the textfield with the background and setting the border to null, Or by creating a custom JtextField implementation and override those methods, or by doing it the hard way and override Jlabel class to put in the feature of changing the text but that is harder than the two other recomended ways.

Comment: *"Anything is possible."*  Much less is sensible.

Comment: @AndrewThompson oh well i guess you are right, the "Anything  is possible" has a lot of conditions following it... :3

Comment: Nvm, got it by using `field.setBackground(null)` and `field.setBorder(null)`, but thanks :)